# Exclude sub-directory from mod rewrite rule

Tags: jquery, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the next htaccess in my root directory:

```
# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

How can exclude my next subfolder, http:// rootdir/demos?

So in demos all my subfolders work in normal way?
Because [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) is broken in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this before your other rewriting rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(demos)($|/) - [L]
```

It will stop the rewrite if the condition is met

Comment: thats great, work like a charm! thank you very much. :)